# less -R does not show colors when processing ANSI colored text via a pipe

Tags: ubuntu, colors, less, terraform

The command `terraform show` does NOT show colored text but the command `terraform show | less` shows output with what seem to be text color *codes*:

```
ESC[0m#module.vpc.module.label.data.null_data_source.tags_as_list_of_maps[2]: data "null_data_source" "tags_as_list_of_maps" {
ESC[1mESC[0mhas_computed_defaultESC[0mESC[0m = "default"
ESC[1mESC[0midESC[0mESC[0m                   = "static"
ESC[1mESC[0minputsESC[0mESC[0m               = {
    "key"   = "IaC"
    "value" = "Terraform"
```

The output from `terraform show | less -R` is just white, as when `terraform show` is run without pipe:

```
# module.subnets.module.public_label.data.null_data_source.tags_as_list_of_maps[0]:
data "null_data_source" "tags_as_list_of_maps" {
    has_computed_default = "default"
    id                   = "static"
    inputs               = {
        "key"   = "Attributes"
        "value" = "k8s-cluster"
```

Any idea why `less` or, possibly, the terminal, is unable to interpret these color codes?

Comment: What about using lowercase `-r` like this: `terraform show | less -r`?

Comment: Many/most programs skip color control chars when their output goes to a non-TTY stream because this would confuse the consumer process.

Comment: @xenoid if you read again you will notice that this is not the issue at all here. The style codes appear in the piped output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you posted uses only two codes:

- `ESC[0m` – Reset / Normal
- `ESC[1m` – Bold or increased intensity

<sup>([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences))</sup>

But wherever the latter appears, the former immediately follows, like this: `ESC[1mESC[0m`. In addition there is an explicit `ESC[0m` at the beginning. In effect all printable fragments are ruled by `ESC[0m`, so the whole snippet is displayed as "normal".

---

To see how the codes work:

```
sed "$(printf 's/ESC/\033/g')" <<EOF
ESC[0mNormal ESC[1mBold ESC[0m Normal
EOF
```

To replicate your result using the published snippet:

```
sed "$(printf 's/ESC/\033/g')" <<EOF
ESC[0m#module.vpc.module.label.data.null_data_source.tags_as_list_of_maps[2]: data "null_data_source" "tags_as_list_of_maps" {
ESC[1mESC[0mhas_computed_defaultESC[0mESC[0m = "default"
ESC[1mESC[0midESC[0mESC[0m                   = "static"
ESC[1mESC[0minputsESC[0mESC[0m               = {
    "key"   = "IaC"

"value" = "Terraform"
EOF
```

And a version where `X` is injected before each `ESC`, so you can see how the codes would work if `ESC[0m` didn't cancel `ESC[1m` immediately:

```
sed "$(printf 's/ESC/X\033/g')" <<EOF
ESC[0m#module.vpc.module.label.data.null_data_source.tags_as_list_of_maps[2]: data "null_data_source" "tags_as_list_of_maps" {
ESC[1mESC[0mhas_computed_defaultESC[0mESC[0m = "default"
ESC[1mESC[0midESC[0mESC[0m                   = "static"
ESC[1mESC[0minputsESC[0mESC[0m               = {
    "key"   = "IaC"

"value" = "Terraform"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Kamil Maciorowski’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1527331/150988#1527367), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences) says
(and you seem to already know) that CSI … **m** sequences
are “Select Graphic Rendition” sequences
— they affect the *appearance* of text. 
But the *color* codes are all two digits
(some non-standard ones are three digits). 
Code 1 is bold or increased intensity.
So, even if there were text between `ESC[1m` and `ESC[0`,
it would still be white, but just bold / brighter.